# Regex to check hsl string format

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to create two regex that check these two types of strings:

```
322°, 79%, 52%
hsl(322°, 79%, 52%)
```

So:

- number between 0 and 259, degree symbol, comma, optional space
- number between 0 and 100, percentage symbol, comma, optional space
- number between 0 and 100, percentage symbol

and the same but with around `hsl(...)`

Examples:

```
// valid
322°, 79%, 52%
0°, 0%, 0% // min values
259°, 100%, 100% // max values
0°, 0%,0% // no spaces
0°,0%, 0% // no spaces
0°,0%,0% // no spaces
hsl(322°, 79%, 52%)
hsl(0°, 0%, 0%)
hsl(259°, 100%, 100%)
hsl(259°,100%, 100%)
hsl(259°, 100%,100%)
hsl(259°,100%,100%)

// Not valid
322, 79%, 52%
322°, 79, 52%
322°, 79%, 52
322°, 79%, 52%
hsl(259°,100%,100%)
```

this is what I tried (this i s the regex for the second format, the first one is similar but without `hsl(...)`):

```js
const regexSimpleFormat = /(hsl\() (([0 - 9] | [1 - 9][0 - 9] | [1 - 2][0 - 5][0 - 9]) °) (, [] ?)(([0 - 9] | [1 - 9][0 - 9] | 100) %)(, [] ?)(([0 - 9] | [1 - 9][0 - 9] | 100) %)(\))/gi

console.log(regexSimpleFormat.test('hsl(22°, 79%, 52%)')) // should be true
console.log(regexSimpleFormat.test('hsl(02°, 79%, 52%)')) // should be false
```

As you can see, it doesn't work because I get false, instead of true. Why? Is there a better way to do what I need?

Comment: Your last invalid example `hsl(259°,100%,100%)` contradicts the second example you gave for the strings `hsl(322°, 79%, 52%)`.

Comment: Normally, I would just grap the digits, convert to numbers and then check if they're within range. Also, you have a lot of spaces in your regex - THEY MATTERS!

Comment: The last two "invalid" examples both appear as "valid" examples as well. I suspect you intended to "cut-paste-edit" but was distracted after the first two steps and forgot to complete the last step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression.

```
(?<!\()\b(?:\d|[1-9]\d|[1-2]\d{2}|3[0-5]\d|360)°(?:, ?(?:[0-9]|[1-9]\d|100)%){2}(?!\))|\bhsl\((?:\d|[1-9]\d|[1-2]\d{2}|3[0-5]\d|360)°(?:, ?(?:[0-9]|[1-9]\d|100)%){2}\)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/htCwmi/1/)

Javascript's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
(?<!\()   negative lookbehind asserts match is not preceded by '('
\b        match a word boundary
(?:\d|[1-9]\d|[1-2]\d{2}|3[0-5]\d|360)
          match an integer 0-360 converted to a string
°         match character
(?:       begin a non-capture group
  , ?     match a comma optionally followed by a space
  (?:[0-9]|[1-9]\d|100)
          match an integer 0-100 converted to a string
  %       match character   
)         end non-capture group
{2}       execute non-capture group twice
(?!\))    negative lookahead asserts match is not followed by ')'
|         or
\bhsl\(   match 'hsl(' preceded by a word boundary
(?:\d|[1-9]\d|[1-2]\d{2}|3[0-5]\d|360)°(?:, ?(?:[0-9]|[1-9]\d|100)%){2}
          as above
\)        match ')'
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though the spaces might make your regex a little more readable, they cause it to fail.
Moreover `hsl` with the brackets should be optional. I also changed the kind you check for spaces and set, that the last part should occur twice to avoid repeatings within the regex.

`^(hsl\()?\s*(([0-9]|([1-9][0-9])|([1-2][0-5][0-9]))°)((,\s*)(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|(100))%)){2}\)?` => https://regex101.com/r/TYR2w2/2

Actually I would recommend you more to just grab the numbers and then check the range via js. It's more readable and easier to understand and debug.

```js
const values = [
  // valid
  "0°, 0%, 0%", // min values
  "259°, 100%, 100%", // max values
  "0°, 0%,0%", // no spaces
  "0°,0%, 0%", // no spaces
  "0°,0%,0%", // no spaces
  "hsl(0°, 0%, 0%)",
  "hsl(259°, 100%, 100%)",
  "hsl(259°,100%, 100%  )",
  "hsl(  259°, 100%,100%)",
  "hsl(259°,100%,100%)",

  // Not valid
  "322, 79%, 52%",
  "322°, 79, 52%",
  "322°, 79%, 52",
  "322°, 79%, 52%",
  "hsl(322°, 79%, 52%)",
"322°, 79%, 52%)",
"hsl(322°, 79%, 52%"
]

const hslRegex = /^(hsl\()?\s*((?<first>[0-9]{1,3})°\s*,\s*(?<second>[0-9]{1,3})%\s*,\s*(?<third>[0-9]{1,3})%)\s*\)?/

let isValid = (hsl) => {
  let matches = hslRegex.exec(hsl);
  if (matches) {
    let isValid = matches.groups.first >= 0 && matches.groups.first <= 259;
    isValid = isValid && matches.groups.second >= 0 && matches.groups.second <= 100;
    isValid = isValid && matches.groups.third >= 0 && matches.groups.third <= 100;
    return isValid;
  }
  return false;
}

values.forEach(x => console.log(x, isValid(x)));
```

NOTE: There are two cases, which will fail right now. They should be invalid, but they aren't:

```
259°, 79%, 52%)
hsl(259°, 79%, 52%"
```

Comment: See @cyborg86pl's comment on another question.

Answer (score 0):

One possible regex for this:

`^(hsl\()?(2[0-5][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])°,\s?(100|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])%,\s?(100|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])%\)?$`

```js
const regexSimpleFormat = /^(hsl\()?(2[0-5][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])°,\s?(100|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])%,\s?(100|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])%\)?$/gi

console.log(regexSimpleFormat.test('hsl(22°, 79%, 52%)')) // should be true
console.log(regexSimpleFormat.test('hsl(02°, 79%, 52%)')) // should be false
```

Main parts explanation:

- **(hsl()?** match "hsl(" 0 or 1 times;
- **(2[0-5][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])**: matches between 0 and 259, not allowing left padding zeros;
- **°,\s?** matches °, and 0 or 1 space;
- **(100|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])** matches between 0 and 100, not allowing left padding zeros;

Comment: To make hsl() optional you need to use logical OR for both cases. Otherwise `259°, 79%, 52%)` or `hsl(259°, 79%, 52%"` examples will also match.